# Drupal Localhost images not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am working on a local drupal site and the images are not appearing. I can upload them into content but they appear as broken links in the admin section and are not shown at all in the front end.

Does anyone have any suggestions or encountered this before?

If it helps I am using core Drupal 7 with MAMP and Bootstrap theme.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is showing as the file location of a broken image?

I assume you already checked the directory and file permissions of the files folder(?).

Comment: I have given all of the folder 777 permissions, what appears is a broken image on the admin side and in the front end nothing at all

Comment: OK. What about the File System settings? Or Private File location (if that's what you're using)? Does the Report status page give any errors? And does the broken image link match the location the image is really at?

Comment: Agree, with above. Look on this page /admin/reports/status to see if it reports any errors with the file system.